# Outbound emails in sharepoint

Tags: email

I wanted to prevent any emails from being sent out mainly the task assignment emails. So I removed the setting in Outbound SMTP server from the Configure outgoing email settings.

Now when an email is generated in SharePoint what happens to the email thats generated (is it generated at all?) . When I re-add the Outbound SMTP server I dont want any possible queued emails sending out, thats if they get generated at all whilst no settings in outgoing email settings.
Using Custom workflow in VB with SPUtility.SendEmail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no email queue in SharePoint. If there is nothing for the email system to connect to the outgoing email is lost.